# Using 'may' and 'might' in AmE

Tags: word-usage, american-english

Do the following sentences sound natural in formal AmE speech:

> - You *may* go now if you want to.
> - You *might* go now if you want to.

I think both of them are correct, but the latter is far more formal or rather literal. Though I doubt about this opinion.

Comment: I'm a native AmE speaker, and I'll say that I've never heard anyone use the "*might*"-construct, and I would never expect to hear it. If someone phrased it that way, I would understand it to be a consciously-British usage, using dry wit to (not-so) subtly indicate you're (ahem)  *suggesting* the person leave.

Comment: Agree with Dan Bron, except *might* calls for *wanted*. But most American speakers would say *can*, anyway! Permissive *may* has been on its deathbed for at least two generations.

Comment: @StoneyB even in formal and written language? (I'm about 'may')

Comment: @DanBron I wonder if you as a native AmE speaker let me know whether the following sentences (which contain different usages of the modal auxiliary verb ‘might’) will make you think that they are stated by a Briton or not?==>
(I wonder if I might put the TV on.) --- (It might rain this afternoon.) --- (I was so angry and might have killed her.) --- (Might you go camping this summer?) --- (I did not see him since this morning. He might have gone out.)

Comment: @A-friend, 1: *TV*: British, 2: *Rain*: normal, 3 : *kill*: normal (though a bit stilted; we'd normally used *could*), 4: *camping*: British, 5: *gone out*: normal.

Comment: @DanBron what about 'may' in the sentence #3 (kill)? Does it sound stilted to? Does 'may' sound normal like 'could' in this sense?

Comment: @A-friend, if you said "*I may have killed her*", it would express uncertainly about whether or not you actually had killed her. You'd only use it in a case like "*I was so drunk, I don't even remember getting behind the wheel. I don't know man, I **may** have killed her.*".

Comment: @DanBron I get your point. This is because probably 'may' expresses a stronger possibility in comparison with 'might' and 'could'. Am I right? If yes anyway the second person will recognize the level of possibility him/herself. Am I right? Not being too strict I guess it should be correct in this sense. Do you agree?

Comment: @A-friend, I'd say "*may*" is qualitatively different in this context, not just quantitatively different. The words "*might*" and "*could*" differ in register, but "*may*" differs in **meaning**. And yes, the person you'd talking to would understand the uncertainty inherent in "*may*" (meaning your interlocutor would know that you don't know, if you follow me).

Comment: Permissive (deontic) *may* still appears in formal contexts, but it is no longer felt to be a solecism to use *can*. Potential (epistemic) *may* is still fine in all registers, though in conversation it has been mostly displaced by *might*.

Comment: @DanBron Thank you very much for all your helpful and informative comments. They were really useful.

Comment: @StoneyB do you believe that using 'may' in #3 (kill) is normal in AE? Could you please explain a little more?
Or you confirm Dan's last comment regarding #3? Does 'may' make one think of quite different concept in this specific context?

Comment: There are two entirely different uses of *may*. One (deontic) expresses permission (*You may go wherever you like*); the other (epistemic) expresses possibility (*He may be dead, or he may be hiding*). It is only deontic *may* which has largely fallen out of use.

Answer (score 1):

*might* is the simple past of may
and I think it's used to express [Subjunctive Mood,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood#English) like *would*, *could* or *should*.

Comment: Could you edit your answer and expand a bit? This is so short it's misleading.

Answer (score 1):

**May** and **Might** both suggest uncertainty, but they offer different degree/perspective/perception. There might/may be situations where they can be interchangeable. (like this very sentence :-)) **may** and **might** - one suggests something that is less likely to happen and the other suggests something that is more likely to happen.

While **might** suggests *possibility*, **may** suggests *probability*.

Consider the following sentences -

1. The CEO **might** resign.
2. The CEO **may** resign.

In both sentences above the uncertainty about his resignation is looming. But there is a difference in register. Sentence #1, *possibility* and sentence #2, *probability*.

In sentence #2, the resignation is likely to happen, but not certain. In sentence #1, there are more chance of resignation, yet uncertain.

Even saying so, in both these sentences the difference is effectively very subtle.

OP's sentence -

**You ____ *(may/might)* go now if you want to.**

We need either **may** or **might** to feel that blank. That blank should contain a word that will suggest uncertainty.

If you use **may**, it's a plain statement of uncertainty. But if you use **might**, you are suggesting there is more chance of your going, though uncertain.

So both are possible depending on context.

Comment: Er, the most likely interpretation for the OP's example would be one of  the speaker giving ***permission.*** E.g. *"You may go to the movies, if you have finished your homework."* which is what a parent could/might say to their child. The parent is giving permission.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence implies some sort of permission is needed.
For example, after a required wait period, someone in charge will then say "You may go now"

The second sentence implies that an opinion is being offered that it is "ok" now to go or "seems like a good time to go".

Answer (score 0):

**Might** sounds very weird.  As for **may**, I was taught in the old school where the word **may** expressed permission.  Almost universally now the word **can** is substituted, even though purists may still consider it sub-standard.